# posting a parameter with integer value using requests lib

Tags: python-2.7, curl, python-requests

I have a curl command that was given to me that I have to convert using requests.

```
curl --request POST "https://www.example.com" --data "user_id=200" --data "user_data=je93jfe92dj220,39fjid20djd93f302,93jfieheio02hfne,902jfoienfieshiu202" --header "Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]"
```

using requests, the call should be

```
hdr = {'Content-Type': 'Content-type: application/json',
       'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN'  }
payload = {"user_id":200,"records":"je93jfe92dj220,39fjid20djd93f302,93jfieheio02hfne,902jfoienfieshiu202"
requests.post('https://www.example.com', headers=hdr, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

This isn't working as I'm getting an error returned that the 'user_id' param must be an integer.  Not sure how to ensure that, as aren't all parameters formatted as strings when sent?  The curl command does work, however.

Answer (score 1):

Im not really sure the reason, but to make this work, just change data=json.dumps(payload) to json=json.dumps(payload). This worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the documentation explains more about the difference between the `data` parameter and the `json` parameter
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

In short:

- `data` can be a dictionary with string `"key":"value"` pairs or a string
- `json` automatically creates the aforementioned dictionary out of the json string
- `json` also adds the `Content-Type : application/json` header automatically

I don't know exactly what the problem was 7 years ago, but this might help someone.